# How to get current user with Trello REST API?

Tags: rest, trello

How can I get the Oauth'ed user's info? Username, etc?

The only way I can see now is to create a board, check the board for "createBoard" action, get the user name from the  action, then delete the board.

Comment: isn't it what you want? [trelloApiTokenMember](https://developers.trello.com/v1.0/reference#tokenstokenmember)

Answer (score 6):

Out of desperation, I found that apparently `https://api.trello.com/1/members/you` or `https://api.trello.com/1/members/me` works. This is not mentioned in the Trello API docs.

Comment: https://api.trello.com/1/members/me is this still working? I tried this and it says error 400

Comment: @Vanz you're passing your API token with the request?

Answer (score 1):

It is not so obviosly from [ApiDoc](https://developers.trello.com/v1.0/reference#tokenstokenmember).
You can get Member object by url:

`https://api.trello.com/1/tokens/token/member?fields=all`

Where `token` is path param, `all` value for `fields` param that allow you to get all fileds from [member object](https://developers.trello.com/reference#member-object). For example username